# Find eigenfunction/eigenvalue pairs of DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenfunctions

I need to find the eigenvalue/eigenfunction pairs of the following DE:

$$x^2y''+3xy'+\lambda y=0, \text{   BC: }y(1)=0, y(e)=0 $$

Through my calculations I have ended up with $\lambda_n = n^2\pi^2 +1$ and the corresponding eigenfunctions as $y_n(x)=sin(n\pi ln(x))$ but when I tried the case when $n=1$ the pair didnt satisfy the equation, any tips on how to go about this?

Comment: This equation you would try the solution $y=ax^r$ as it's an equidimensional eauation

Comment: I got my pairs from considering the equation $x^2y''+3xy'+(1+\alpha)y=0$ (using the standard way of letting $y=x^m$ and finding $m$

Comment: Is there such a name equidimensional equation?  Isn't it a Cauchy-Euler equation?

Comment: What I mean to say is your eigenfunctions are the $x^r$ where the $r$ are the eigenvalues. Your solution should be of the form $y=Ax^{\lambda_1}+Bx^{\lambda_2}$

Comment: I got the r to be complex and hence why I ended up with $sin$'s in my solution

Comment: @Deke. use Euler's formula: $e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$

Comment: A Cauchy-Euler equation can also be called an equidimensional equation.

Comment: @daulomb I used that after getting $m$ to be complex and thats how I ended up with the $sin(n\pi lnx)$ term

Comment: $m=a+ib\Longrightarrow x^m=x^ax^{ib}=x^ae^{ib\ln|x|}=x^a\big(\cos (b\ln |x|)+i\sin (b\ln |x|)\big)$

Comment: Also the analysis will differ depending on $\lambda$ so you have a case system

Comment: @daulomb yep got exactly that and this particular question had BCs $y(1)=0, y(e)=0$ so the $cos$ term disappeared and I was just left with the $sin$